# Ngx-translate Angular Variable value problem

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I try to get value from a component variable to translate with lazyloading

```
<label class="text-white" >{{ 'profil.city' | translate }} &nbsp;</label>
<input class="text-white bg-transparent" value="{{user.town}}">   /* Works*/

<label class="text-white" >{{ 'profil.sex' | translate }} &nbsp;</label>
<input class="text-white bg-transparent" value="{{ '{{user.sex}}' | translate}}"> /* Don't Works */
```

I get error with the

```
 {{ '{{user.sex}}' | translate}}"
```

I Just want to get user.sex value which is a entry in the language.json to translate.

How can I get the value to translate it Correctly ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
 {{'user.sex' | translate }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to normal evaluation instead of template expansion:

```
[value]="'user.sex' | translate"
```

or also this will work

```
value={{ 'user.sex' | translate }}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the semi colon do like this :value="{{user.sex | translate}}"